# In fortran: Is CONJG(Z) equivialent to DCONJG(Z) when compiling with -fdefault-real-8?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

If in existing code there are calls to `DCONJG(Z)` where Z is declared to be `COMPLEX*16`. Can the `DCONJG` call be replaced with `CONJG` when the `-fdefault-real-8` flag is added?

If `Z` is defined as `double complex` does this still apply?

In the existing code `double complex` and `complex*16` have both been used to increase precision (and should be equivalent). With the `-fdefault-real-8` flag applied, do `double complex` map to `complex*32`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can the DCONJG call be replaced with CONJG when the -fdefault-real-8
>   flag is added?

Yes, the standard `conjg` will return a value of the same kind as its argument, irrespective of the compilation settings.  Kind-specific variants of intrinsic functions, such as `dconjg`, are generally deprecated precisely because they are not kind-indifferent.

> If Z is defined as double complex does this still apply?

Yes.

> And is double complex equivalent to complex with the flag applied
>   (same for double precision and real)?

If you mean does that compilation flag also affect the size of the real and imaginary components of a complex value then yes, it does.

EDIT

I don't know what `gfortran` means by the non-standard (never was, isn't, and probably never will be) kind specification `complex*32`.  But the compiler is reasonably well documented so have a scout yourself.  Personally I'd stick to one of the standard ways of specifying a complex number's kind, in which case the standard assures you that the kind specified, e.g. `complex(real64)`, means the kind of each component of the complex number.

Comment: Last question, I got a little bit confused by table 2.2 in http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/6j4m0vn6o/index.html#z40007362063 (if it applies to gfortran?), I read it so that `double complex` would map to `complex*32` with flag applied. On a different note, could I use `complex*16` and `complex*32` safely in the same arithmetic expression?